# CreateScaledBitmap returns a blank image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have been trying to follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527745/1352702
, to create a scaled bitmap instead of just drawing a bitmap on the canvas, to solve some memory issues.

Here is my code,

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
options.inSampleSize = 8;

Bitmap s000 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("zoo" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
int X = c.getWidth()/2 - s000.getWidth()/2 ;
int Y = c.getHeight()/2 - s000.getHeight()/2 ;
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(s000, s000.getWidth(), s000.getHeight(), true);
```

But it just creates a blank screen.
Also how to pass the position parameters of the image (X and Y respectively) in the createScaledBitmap method ?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I had the same issue when trying to resize certain hi-resolution grayscale PNGs : they were properly loaded by `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`, then `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` turned them into black pictures.

Turns out that, on API 26+, Android doesn't know how to handle bitmaps whose `ColorSpace` is not properly detected ("Unknown"), and messes up the resizing.

The working solution for my app was to define a preferred ColorSpace at load time :

```java
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            options.inPreferredColorSpace = ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.SRGB);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeXXX(<whatever method you fancy>, options);
```